# Error when news scraping with GoogleNews - "No module named GoogleNews"

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to use the GoogleNews API which was recently released to get some articles from google, provided by this website https://pypi.org/project/GoogleNews/.

But in the terminal i get the error "*No module named 'GoogleNews*' ", even though I've run the

```
pip install GoogleNews
```

Here's the full program I'm trying to run:

```
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
googlenews = GoogleNews()

googlenews.search('Corona')

googlenews.result()
```

Is it something I'm missing? Pretty damn new to assess if APIs are good/working/not working etc.

Is there something that you guys usually look for when trying to find a tool to get for example news as easily as possible?

Comment: You're probably not installing the library to the same Python which you're using to run the  program. Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: When you have a ModuleNotFoundError you should check your environment, are you executing a version of python that should be able to find the module. when asking a question about this error, you should provide details about your environment such as what versions of python are installed, are you using virtual environments, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be possible that you're messing up the Python versions.

If you install a module using `pip` you should execute your Python code with Python 2.7. If you want to use Python version 3 you need to use `pip3` and execute your code using `python3 myScript.py`.

Try the following:

1. Make a file called **myScript.py**

```
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
googlenews = GoogleNews()

googlenews.search('Corona')

googlenews.result()
```

2. Install the GoogleNews module

```
pip3 install GoogleNews
```

3. Execute your code

```
python3 myScript.py
```

If you don't have Python 3 yet, [download it here](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Pip3 comes automatically with Python 3.